# Spring data couchbase N1QL with list parameter

Tags: spring, spring-data, couchbase, sql++

I would like to retrieve the first object containing at least one of the given tags in parameter.

```
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE SOME t IN tags SATISFIES t IN [\"#{#currentTags}\"] " +
        "END AND #{#n1ql.filter} LIMIT 1")
RecipeEntry findFirstContainingTags(@Param("currentTags")List<String> tags);
```

But the generated N1QL query is

```
"SELECT * FROM contents WHERE SOME t IN tags SATISFIES t IN ["tag1,tag2"] END LIMIT 1"
```

The query expected is

```
"SELECT * FROM contents WHERE SOME t IN tags SATISFIES t IN ["tag1","tag2"] END LIMIT 1"
```

So i expect that my parameter currentTags will be converted into ["tag1","tag2"] not ["tag1,tag2"]

Is there a mean to generate this query with Spring data ?

Comment: Did you try this query = @Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE SOME t IN tags SATISFIES t IN :#{#currentTags} +
        "END AND #{#n1ql.filter} ORDER BY creationDate DESC LIMIT 1")

Comment: what happen if you remove the quotes? ( SATISFIES t IN [#{#currentTags}] )

Comment: You can't use Jpa Query  IN ["params"]. This is not native query.

Comment: Thanks for your answers but :#{#currentTags} and removing quotes doesn't work :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For information, below what i have done :

- I use jackson objectMapper to convert my list of String to a json
- Give the json as parameter

Service :

```
public RecipeEntry findMostRecentWithAtLeastTags(List<String> tags) {
    RecipeEntry recipeEntry = null;
    try {
        String tagsArray = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(tags);
        recipeEntry = ((RecipeQueryRepository) this.queryRepository).findMostRecentWithAtLeastTags(tagsArray);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error while retrieving most recent recipe with given tags", e);
    }

    return recipeEntry;
}
```

Repository :

```
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE status = 'PUBLISHED' AND (EVERY t IN #{#currentTags} SATISFIES t IN tags END) " +
        "AND #{#n1ql.filter} ORDER BY publishDate DESC LIMIT 1")
RecipeEntry findMostRecentWithAtLeastTags(@Param("currentTags") String tags);
```